# Friendlier form validation with error logging on all inputs

Tags: php

I am tying to refine how my application handles drawing forms and validating their inputs. **In particular, I want the option of testing ALL inputs for validation instead of just returning on the first error I find!** I'd like to accomplish a structure like this...

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    if (check_field($_POST['name']))
    {
        $form_errors['name'] = 'Name is invalid';
    }

    if (check_field($_POST['email']))
    {
        $form_errors['email'] = 'E-mail is invalid';
    }

    if (count($form_errors) == 0)
    {
        // All validations succeeded
        // Continue processing the form
        // Show confirmation for user
        // DO NOT REDRAW THE FORM!!!
    }
    else
    {
        // Somehow jump to the SHOW_FORM below
    }
}
elseif (SHOW_FORM)
{
    // Show ALL errors we have collected, if any
    print_r($form_errors);

    /*
    * A block of code that draws the form!
    * A block of code that draws the form!
    * A block of code that draws the form!
    */
}
else
{
    // Show a list of records to edit
}
```

I have been accomplishing this with functions up until now. I have 1.) a function that draws the form and prints the contents of the $form_errors array if any and 2.) a function that validates the form inputs on submission. If the validation function returns false (which it does if any errors are found), the user lands back on the form with all of their errors on display.

Writing a pair of functions for every new form has become cumbersome and leads to a lot of repeat code. If possible, I'd like to abandon this practice and just have my parent page validate form inputs, but default to simply drawing the form. I would like assistance in structuring the page in this way.

Comment: Remove the else block/s and just let it continue though.

Comment: That won't work for me. If the form process succeeded, I don't want it to redraw the form.

Comment: Then your most likely want to redirect to a success page etc, so you use a header, or if not add an if/else based upon if $form_errors is empty outside of the POST logic.

Comment: @Andrew The question is implied in the very last sentence -- just after your quote. I am unsure of how to structure the page in a way that accomplishes what I described above.

Comment: Well it is too broad of a question, to help you restructure your pages, especially considering we cant see all your pages.

Comment: I am not married to the above structure. It's simply an illustration of what I'm trying to do. The question is straight forward. I have a form. I have a series of validations for the form's inputs. I want to run through all of my checks, record all of the errors, and return to the form IF there are any errors. Otherwise, I do something else. I can accomplish this by making functions out of the form and its set of validation checks, but I am ASKING if there are better ways of doing this. A change in structure? Anything?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some ideas:
Put your forms into their own files with nothing but the html & code to display errors only (this is called a View).

Post to a page that handles the post (this is called a Controller).

In the page that handles the post, only validate using re-usable functions that you have included from another file. For example the validation function might look like this: `validate_email($_POST['email']);` or `validate($_POST['email'], 'email');`, or `validate($_POST, ['email' => 'email']);`